# Develop a function into Taylor series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Please guide me through the process of developing the following function into Taylor series: $$ f(x) = \frac{x+1}{x^2-5x+6}  $$ for $x_0=0$.

I got stuck in $ f(x) = \frac{x+1}{x^2-5x+6}= \frac{x+1}{(x-3)(x-2)} = \frac{x+1}{3-x}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x/2} $

The last fraction is the geometric sequence but I'm not sure what to do with the left one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens that$$f(x)=-\frac3{x-2}+\frac4{x-3}=\frac3{2-x}-\frac4{3-x}=\frac{3/2}{1-x/2}-\frac{4/3}{1-x/3}.$$
Now, use the geometric series.